# Non-Serializable data member with WCF

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, serialization

I have a non-serialized object and I dont have access to source codes. What are options to make it serializable so that I can send it over the network using WCF?

There is no serious reasons that the object is not serializable. The class is not serializable because its author just did not mark it that way and I do not have access to class.

Answer (score 5):

Check this out:

```
public class Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Values { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Derived : Base 
{
    public double X { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = new Derived() { X = 3.1415, Values = new List<int> { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5 }, Name = "Pi" };
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(Derived)).Serialize(stream, d);
        string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer());
    }
}
```

Apparently you can make a derived class serializable. The resulting string contains the values for the base class properties as well.

Comment: Thanks ! I see you are using memory stream. Can't I directly send memory stream ( bytearray) over the network ? Please forgive my ignorance and this is just a thought - why do I need to send XML - if memory byte works?

Comment: @user1630853 This is just my proof of concept that the base class properties are serialized. XML serialization has the advantage that it is human-readable and simple. Use the simplest serialization that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

If the class isn't written with serialization in mind from the start, I'd suggest that you make a simple [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) class that is your data contract and copy the data to that one. To ease up copying you could use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) if there are many properties.

It is always a good idea to separate the protocol contract (which a WCF data contract class is) into a separate class that you have tight control over when/how it changes as any changes will break clients of your service.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a "proxy" since you cannot alter the other code.

It can be a basic DTO/POCO object that contains the properties of interest.

Anders already said this.

Here is a link to the "pattern"

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternProxy.aspx

It's not a direct to wcf concept.  The link is provided to provide some "food for thought".

You can write a basic "translator" between your [Serializable] object, and the original one.